# Travis-CI : ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, travis-ci, alsa

I have an open source project that implements - next to other functionality - a media player that is supposed to be remote controlled.

The source code is available under https://github.com/wzr1337/rsiServer

As a CI solution, I use Travis-CI. UNfortunately, the build breaks because of issues with the ALSA Layer in the virtual build environment:

```
Starting test suite "general Tests"
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4248:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4727:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
[../deps/mpg123/src/output/alsa.c:165] error: cannot open device default
```

I tried a bunch of things already, but they did not resolve the issue. I think the ALSA has to be told to render into a "null" card, but how to configure travis corretly for that?

My current config is:

```
{
  "dist": "trusty",
  "sudo": "required",
  "language": "node_js",
  "node_js": "6",
  "addons": {
    "apt": {
      "sources": [
        "ubuntu-toolchain-r-test"
      ],
      "packages": [
        "gcc-6",
        "g++-6",
        "cmake"
      ]
    }
  },
  "env": "http_proxy=''",
  "git": {
    "submodules": false
  },
  "before_install": [
    "git submodule update --init",
    "sudo usermod -a -G audio travis",
    "sudo apt-get install -y portaudio19-dev",
    "sudo apt-get install -y libasound2-dev alsa-utils alsa-oss",
    "sudo modprobe snd-dummy",
    "sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/local/bin/gcc",
    "sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-6 /usr/local/bin/g++",
    "export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-6",
    "export CXX=/usr/bin/g++-6",
    "gcc -v && g++ -v && cmake --version",
    "sudo apt-get install build-essential node-gyp",
    "npm install -g gulp@3.9.1"
  ],
  "install": [
    "npm install"
  ],
  "script": [
    "export AUDIODEV=null",
    "npm test"
  ],
  "global_env": "AUDIODEV=null",
  "group": "stable",
  "os": "linux"
}
```

The build log can be found here : https://travis-ci.org/wzr1337/rsiServer/jobs/258736222

Can you please help me to resolve the sound card / ALSA issue?

Thanks

Comment: You are telling `mpg123` to use the `default` device.

Comment: @CL. I would assume this correct because I simulate only one device (null) on Travis, so it will be the default, right?

Comment: No. Anyway, what is that `AUDIODEV=null` doing there?

Comment: @CL. It is supposed to tell the ASAP to use the null device.. AFAIK.. So it won't render actual audio

Comment: You have to tell `mpg123` to use `null`, or redefine the `default` device to point to `null`. (I don't know Travis CI.)

Comment: Travis is a Ubuntu system..